# How to make health decay over time? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hello I'm very new to ActionScript 3.0 and I really need some help :P
I'm trying to make like a timing(?) game.
Basically this health is supposed to randomly decay and the person playing it has to click a button when the health reaches 1000.

I've managed to make the health bar and make it go down when I click the button but how do I make it so the health bar decays over time?

The maximum health will be 10000 and i hope the health goes down like 80~90 (random) per 0.1 second?

this is the code so far I've made

```
var maxHP:int = 10000;
var currentHP:int = maxHP;
var percentHP:Number = currentHP / maxHP;
var randNum:Number=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+900;

function updateHealthBar():void
{
percentHP = currentHP / maxHP;
healthBar.barColor.scaleX = percentHP;
}

function attackHealth():void
{
for(currentHP = maxHP; currentHP > 0; currentHP-= 1)
{
    updateHealthBar();
}
}

attackButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, attackButtonClicked);

function attackButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
currentHP -= 800;
if(currentHP <= 0)
{
    currentHP = 0;
    trace("You died! :P");
}
setInterval(attackHealth, 500);
updateHealthBar();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html)

```
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

//it will trigger every 100ms and keep repeats indefinitely
 var t:Timer = new Timer(100);
 t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);


  private function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void {
       var damage:int = 80 + int(Math.random()*11); //[80, 90]

       //do something with damage

  }
```

Comment: I have put the timer code but it says
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventlistener through a reference with static type flash.utils:Timer.
Here is the code I put:
var t:Timer = new Timer(100);

t.addEventlistener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);

function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void {
 currentHP -= 5
 updateHealthBar();
}

Comment: Also I did the
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.events.*;